# qmake can't evaluate a proper variable

Tags: qt, qmake

I'd like to share my build version in the app but I can't get that thing to work... this is a part of my .pro file...

```
LITERAL_HASH = "foo";
BUILD = "$${LITERAL_HASH}{\"sexy Installer\"},(0x12345678),1,0,3";
DEPLOYMENT.installer_header = $$(BUILD);

message(bar .$$(BUILD).)
```

and when I run qmake from Qt menu the output is:

```
Project MESSAGE: bar ..
```

I'm doing everything according to the docs and still that variable seems to be empty...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$${BUILD}` instead of `$$(BUILD)`. The `$()` operator accesses environment variables, not .pro file variables.