# Using qmake variables

Tags: variables, qmake

Is there a way to get qmake to substitute a custom variable like this? In other words, I want $(LIBS) to be replaced with the variable LIBS, so that I can easily change the include path from machine to machine. Many thanks in advance!

```
LIBS = c:/tmp/libs.pfo
INCLUDEPATH += . \
$(LIBS)/OpenCV2.1-msvc/include \
$(LIBS)/OpenCV2.1-msvc/modules/core/include \
$(LIBS)/OpenCV2.1-msvc/modules/imgproc/include \
...
```

I have also tried this to no avail:

```
LIBS = c:/tmp/libs.pfo
INCLUDEPATH += . \
$$quote($$LIBS/OpenCV2.1-msvc/include) \
$$quote($$LIBS/OpenCV2.1-msvc/modules/core/include) \
$$quote($$LIBS/OpenCV2.1-msvc/modules/imgproc/include) \
...
```

Comment: Big warning: `LIBS` is a built-in variable that is used by qmake for internal purposes. Do not use it for anything else or qmake might eat your children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After seeing another thread I tried a third trick, which worked! [qmake can't evaluate a proper variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215257/qmake-cant-evaluate-a-proper-variable)

```
LIBS = c:/tmp/libs.pfo
INCLUDEPATH += . \
$$quote($${LIBS}/OpenCV2.1-msvc/include) \
$$quote($${LIBS}/OpenCV2.1-msvc/modules/core/include) \
$$quote($${LIBS}/OpenCV2.1-msvc/modules/imgproc/include) \
...
```

Comment: Use of $${VAR} is explained [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#variables) in the documentation. ( Although I found this post before I managed to find that. )